# Hamburger menu does not close after I click on it (bootstrap)

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I am having an issue with hamburger menu. I click on it and it opens the menu but when I click it again, it doesn't close the menu. It seems to flash so maybe it closed and reopen on the click. What is wrong with the code below that is causing the hamburger menu to not close?

```
<section id="nav-bar">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/../#"><img src="../img/logo.png"></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/../#top">HOME</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/../#about">ABOUT US</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/../#courses">OUR COURSES</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/../#services">OUR SERVICES</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/../#testimonials">TESTIMONIALS</a>
              </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/../#contact">CONTACT</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working with bootstrap 4.5.0.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<section id="nav-bar">

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/../#"><img src="../img/logo.png"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/../#top">HOME</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/../#about">ABOUT US</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/../#courses">OUR COURSES</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/../#services">OUR SERVICES</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/../#testimonials">TESTIMONIALS</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/../#contact">CONTACT</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</section>
```